# Magento 2 - Get attribute options and sort order

Tags: magento2, attributes, eav

I need to get the label and sort order (as defined in backend) of all the options of a custom attribute, programmatically.

I'm using this interface: `Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface`

This is what I tried already:

```
// Access to the attribute interface
$attribute = $this->_attributeRepository->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'attribute_code');

// Get an array of options
$options = $attribute->getOptions();

// Get the label and sort order of each option
foreach ($options as $option) {
    var_dump($option->getLabel()); // Works OK
    var_dump($option->getSortOrder()); // Always returns NULL
}
```

I have double checked and there exists a sort order, both in database and in admin area, but the `getSortOrder` method always returns NULL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
//Use the following code.

function getExistingOptions( $object_Manager ) {

$eavConfig = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

$optionsExists = array();

foreach($options as $option) {
    $optionsValues[] = $option['value'];
    $optionsExists[] = $option['label'];
}

return $optionsExists;
```

}

Click here for detailed explanation.
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/code-snippets/get-magento-attribute-options-programmatically/

Comment: How to get the options in ascending order

Answer (score 1):

Use following code for getting attribute options and sort order.

```
$eavConfig = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code');

$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(); // for attribute option.

$attribute->getPosition(); // for attribute sort order or option.
```

Answer (score 0):

By Default its giving you the result sorted so if you want store the sortorderid in that array then you just store the index value of that loop.

Answer (score 0):

Long answer:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace/Module/Model;

class Options
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $attrOptionCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Options constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\CollectionFactory $attrOptionCollectionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->attrOptionCollectionFactory = $attrOptionCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute $attribute
     */
    public function fullAllOptions($attribute)
    {
        $collection = $this->attrOptionCollectionFactory->create()
            ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getAttributeId())
            ->setStoreFilter($attribute->getStoreId())
            ->load();

        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterface $option */
        foreach($collection as $option) {
            $label = $option->getLabel();
            $value = $option->getValue();
            $sort = $option->getSortOrder();
        }
    }
}
```

Short answer:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute $attribute
 */
public function fullAllOptions($attribute)
{
    $sort = 0;
    foreach ($attribute->getOptions() as $option) {
        $label = $option->getLabel();
        $value = $option->getValue();
        $sort = $sort++;    // because this collection already sorted by sortOrder field
    }
}
```